# How to fix position of nodes when using draw_circular in networkx?

Tags: python, networkx

I want to draw two graphs are almost same, the only difference is that the second one will have some edges grayed out. And I want nodes in the second graph stay exactly where they are in the first graph.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the optional `pos` argument.

In your case using circular layout `pos = nx.circular_layout(G)`.  Then you call the plotting commands like `nx.draw(G, pos, other_arguments...)`.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!